# Postgresql OVERLAPS performance on big datasets

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I am struggling to build a performant query using OVERLAPS.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE date_range_table
(
  id int NOT NULL,
  item_id int NOT NULL,
  item1_id int NOT NULL,
  item2_id int NOT NULL,
  item3_id int NOT NULL,
  item4_id int NULL,
  item5_id int NULL,
  date_from date NOT NULL,
  date_to date NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT pk_date_range_table PRIMARY KEY (id)
  -- Some other constraints
)

-- Unique constraints(partial)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_date_range_table_items_null
ON date_range_table USING btree
(item_id, item1_id, item2_id, item3_id, date_from, date_to)
WHERE item4_id IS NULL AND item5_id IS NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_date_range_table_items_not_null
ON date_range_table USING btree
(item_id, item1_id, item2_id, item3_id, item4_id, item5_id, date_from, date_to)
WHERE item4_id IS NOT NULL AND item5_id IS NOT NULL;
```

I also have the same table as a staging table(ETL).

```
staging_date_range_table
```

Now i need to check for any straddles(OVERLAPS) that might exists in the staging_date_range_table vs date_range_table.

What i have so far:

```
SELECT count(t.*)
FROM staging_date_range_table t
JOIN date_range_table td
  on
      t.item_id = td.item_id
  AND t.item1_id = td.item1_id
  AND t.item2_id = td.item2_id
  AND t.item3_id = td.item3_id
  AND COALESCE(t.item4_id, 0) = COALESCE(td.item4_id, 0)
  AND COALESCE(t.item5_id, 0) = COALESCE(td.item5_id, 0)

WHERE (t.date_from, t.date_to) OVERLAPS (td.date_from, td.date_to)
```

Working set:

```
staging_date_range_table: 100k rows

date_range_table: 20mil rows
```

This will run for 10h's +

Any idea on how to speed this up?

========== UPDATE ==========

Explain from a smaller staging set(COLUMN NAMES REPLACED):

```
"Update on _2103301527_2fd34e_date_range_table t  (cost=95785.89..1923251.02 rows=1 width=3560)"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=95785.89..1923251.02 rows=1 width=3560)"
"        Merge Cond: ((td.item_id = t._fcd195352fb4bd386b496c42e58904bb) AND (td.item1_id = t._2c7d5721c3def81d253271f0c2065421))"
"        Join Filter: ((COALESCE(t._842c0c2670edb9fe4ede4cc9e4bac082, '0'::bigint) = COALESCE(td.item4_id, '0'::bigint)) AND (COALESCE(t._522ffbc4b23b13d84bad22e151f4c9df, '0'::bigint) = COALESCE(td.item5_id, '0'::bigint)) AND (t._9afea17b49bfb167b72276a824712179 = td.item2_id) AND (t._452088c89804e1b5d34a6d266ca6c51a = td.item3_id) AND ((t._3027783fd3d10afad84a9a15552b3445 <> td.date_from) OR (t._0dc00dd4dfdbf2864a0cdf57034916c2 <> td.date_to)) AND ""overlaps""((t._3027783fd3d10afad84a9a15552b3445)::timestamp with time zone, (t._0dc00dd4dfdbf2864a0cdf57034916c2)::timestamp with time zone, (td.date_from)::timestamp with time zone, (td.date_to)::timestamp with time zone))"
"        ->  Index Scan using index_iip_on_... on date_range_table td  (cost=0.56..1594851.20 rows=8202145 width=62)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=95785.34..95889.13 rows=20759 width=3550)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=95785.34..95837.23 rows=20759 width=3550)"
"                    Sort Key: t._fcd195352fb4bd386b496c42e58904bb, t._2c7d5721c3def81d253271f0c2065421"
"                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _2103301527_2fd34e_date_range_table t  (cost=1353.30..30862.77 rows=20759 width=3550)"
"                          Recheck Cond: (_rs < 100)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_2f01fb51327eb8ab144f717aad1c80487b711093f6efd7af3a  (cost=0.00..1348.11 rows=20759 width=0)"
"                                Index Cond: (_rs < 100)"
```

Actual explain(COLUMN NAMES REPLACED):

```
"Update on _2103301527_2fd34e_staging_date_range_table t  (cost=2329696.92..2475637.46 rows=188 width=2742) (actual time=167057.275..167057.277 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=417 read=370671, temp read=269876 written=270422"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=2329696.92..2475637.46 rows=188 width=2742) (actual time=167057.274..167057.275 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Merge Cond: ((td.item1_id = t._9afea17b49bfb167b72276a824712179) AND (td.item_id = t._fcd195352fb4bd386b496c42e58904bb) AND ((COALESCE(td.item4_id, '0'::bigint)) = (COALESCE(t._842c0c2670edb9fe4ede4cc9e4bac082, '0'::bigint))) AND ((COALESCE(td.item5_id, '0'::bigint)) = (COALESCE(t._522ffbc4b23b13d84bad22e151f4c9df, '0'::bigint))) AND (td.item2_id = t._2c7d5721c3def81d253271f0c2065421) AND (td.item3_id = t._452088c89804e1b5d34a6d266ca6c51a))"
"        Join Filter: (((t._3027783fd3d10afad84a9a15552b3445 <> td.date_from) OR (t._0dc00dd4dfdbf2864a0cdf57034916c2 <> td.date_to)) AND ""overlaps""((t._3027783fd3d10afad84a9a15552b3445)::timestamp with time zone, (t._0dc00dd4dfdbf2864a0cdf57034916c2)::timestamp with time zone, (td.date_from)::timestamp with time zone, (td.date_to)::timestamp with time zone))"
"        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 187204665"
"        Buffers: shared hit=417 read=370671, temp read=269876 written=270422"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=1980647.14..2001152.50 rows=8202145 width=62) (actual time=19793.734..24438.091 rows=8176251 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: td.item1_id, td.item_id, (COALESCE(td.item4_id, '0'::bigint)), (COALESCE(td.item5_id, '0'::bigint)), td.item2_id, td.item3_id"
"              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 658152kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=382 read=339568, temp read=264238 written=264767"
"              ->  Seq Scan on date_range_table td  (cost=0.00..421967.45 rows=8202145 width=62) (actual time=0.021..4518.051 rows=8202145 loops=1)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=378 read=339568"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=348994.45..349641.59 rows=129428 width=2732) (actual time=614.072..9890.352 rows=187202992 loops=1)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=35 read=31103, temp read=5638 written=5655"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=348994.45..349318.02 rows=129428 width=2732) (actual time=614.069..920.578 rows=129777 loops=1)"
"                    Sort Key: t._9afea17b49bfb167b72276a824712179, t._fcd195352fb4bd386b496c42e58904bb, (COALESCE(t._842c0c2670edb9fe4ede4cc9e4bac082, '0'::bigint)), (COALESCE(t._522ffbc4b23b13d84bad22e151f4c9df, '0'::bigint)), t._2c7d5721c3def81d253271f0c2065421, t._452088c89804e1b5d34a6d266ca6c51a"
"                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 36632kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=35 read=31103, temp read=5638 written=5655"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on _2103301527_2fd34e_staging_date_range_table t  (cost=0.00..32755.85 rows=129428 width=2732) (actual time=0.574..168.827 rows=129777 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: (_rs < 100)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=35 read=31103"
"Planning Time: 4.976 ms"
"Execution Time: 167135.877 ms"
```

========== UPDATE ==========

Increase the `generate_series` bottom left.

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gP5MXDJn4hA8UkksS8egZq/5)

Comment: Hard to say without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

Comment: I suggest setting up a sample at https://www.db-fiddle.com/ (including an explain plan) so people can rapidly reproduce and try out things.

Comment: @Dominik Fiddle added

Comment: `WHERE item5_id IS NOT NULL AND item5_id IS NOT NULL;` <<-- Typo?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Explain added.

Comment: @wildplasser Yea. thx. Updated

Comment: Your partial index is not usable (does not add up to all) I'd prefer a (NON UNIQUE)  index on all itemX_ids, and maybe with the dates first.

Comment: @wildplasser This is replicating our existing table. I unfortunately can't change it.

Comment: But: do you realise that the case `WHERE item4_id IS NOT NULL AND item5_id IS NULL;` (or vice versa) is not covered by any index?

Comment: @Willem My advice would also be to have a non unique index on all item columns, try to get rid of the coalesce if you don't need it and try to `SET work_mem TO 'xGB';` If your entries fit into RAM e.g. for sorts you'll get a inmemory quicksort instead of heavily using IO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try `daterange` instead of separate "from" and "to" dates and use the "overlaps" operator `&&`. That allows you to use a GiST index, and you can perhaps get a fast nested loop join.The reasoning behind that is that the majority of the rows from the merge join are filtered out by the `OVERLAPS` condition.

```
WHERE daterange(t.date_from,  t.date_to,  '[]')
   && daterange(td.date_from, td.date_to, '[]')
```

Suggested index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON date_range_table USING gist
   (daterange(date_from, date_to, '[]'));
```

Comment: Is there any way to re-write the query to be more performant or is this just the nature of the beast and i will have to wait for the query to finish?

Comment: Perhaps. I outlined something you could try in my answer.

Comment: I finally had some time to run some benchmarks and the index with the `daterange` did the trick. Thx so much. Bounty incoming ^^

Comment: @Willem out of curiosity: How much benefit did you roughly get from this optimization?

Comment: @Dominik In the end i used a btree-gist for my unique columns with the daterange. 100k in ETL table. 10mil in DB. Went from 10h to 6min.